# Get or create no-required field Option<T>

Tags: rust

There is a way to achieve get or create like upsert in db vocab for no required field.

In the following code [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=026296a34ea322bbd21194d31a74cb18) fail because self.option is borrowed.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    option: Option<i32>,
}

impl A {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { option: None }
    }

    fn option_or_new(&mut self) -> &i32 {
        if let Some(i) = &self.option { // `self.option` is borrowed here
            &i
        } else {
            let i = 0;
            self.option = Some(i); // cannot assign to `self.option` because it is borrowed
            self.option.as_ref().unwrap()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A::new();
    let i = a.option_or_new();
    println!("{}",i);
}
```

I have to use unsafe code for resolved this issue, or does it exist an idiomatic way for that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`get_or_insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert) or [`get_or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert_with):

```rust
impl A {
    fn option_or_new(&mut self) -> &i32 {
        self.option.get_or_insert(0)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b66b3a800c7dd000a0df9bec3d33b3c5)